# Grizzly to be used in Async write mode

Tags: multithreading, http, asynchronous, glassfish, grizzly

I am using **Glassfish 3.1** to serve static contents. 
The Client  HTTP Get Requests are processed by Spring's Dispatcher Servlet with the parameter async-supported set to true. The static content are binary images of approx size of 50MB. My main concern with using Glassfish as static content provider was scalability until I stumbled upon the below parameter which set Grizzly in Async Write mode.

```
-Dcom.grizzly.http.asyncwrite.enabled=true
```

After setting the above JVM parameter, I could see the worker thread being released quickly which earlier were being held for the entire duration of a file transfer.

I am aware that I need to configure certain parameters (e.g BufferMemory, Acceptor threads etc) in order to make this production ready.

My questions are,

- What are the effects of adding this JVM paramter.
- Is there a definitive list of parameters which I need to tune to make this work with lesser side effects?
- What are the alternatives to the above configuration.

The official documentation are single liners and does not give proper examples.

Comment: Which Glassfish version are you using?

Comment: @alexey Glassfish 3.1 , the most important detail that I missed. Will edit the question as well.

Comment: Are you using any JavaEE features except Servlets? Maybe in your case you could use plain Grizzly HttpServer, which has more features to deal with static files comparing to Glassfish 3.1... Or you can use Glassfish 4.1

Comment: @alexey Well, I use JEE features.There is certainly a plan to go to Glassfish4.1, but that's 6 months down the line. Is async mode (write) default on grizzly shipped with Glasfish 4.1? Are there any drawbacks of enabling the grizzly for async writes? Would appreciate if anyone provides me more information on my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that setting `-Dcom.grizzly.http.asyncwrite.enabled=true` sets Grizzily in async mode. Of course you need to fine tune other parameters to make it production ready. 
Glassfish  4.1 comes bundled with asycn write mode.